# What are the bonuses of Dead Island Riptide Limited Edition?

Tags: dead-island-riptide

I know DIR limited edition comes with a steelbook gamecase, but is that it? no extra characters or weapons?...I don't want to pay an extra 20 bucks just for a steelbook case. 
Also could you cut straight to the answer, I couldn't care less about the other editions. (I just want to know the difference between Dead Island Riptide and Dead Island Riptide Limited Edition). -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it´s only the steelbook. For DLC and such you should buy the Special edition.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I'm paying 25 bucks for a preowned limited edition, when i could pay 18 bucks for a brand new special edition...the only problem is billing. Thanks again.